# How to concatenate a Date inside array filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, date, array-filter

```
var monthStartDate = new Date(); 
monthStartDate.setUTCDate(1);
var weekOneStartDate = JSON.stringify(monthStartDate.toJSON().substring(0, 10));

var monthEndDate = new Date(monthStartDate); 
monthEndDate.setUTCMonth(monthEndDate.getUTCMonth() + 1);
monthEndDate.setUTCDate(0);
var weekFiveEndDate = JSON.stringify(monthEndDate.toJSON().substring(0, 10));
document.write(weekOneStartDate)
document.write(weekFiveEndDate)
  
if(res.data.items.length > 0 )
{  
  var DateArray = res.data.items.filter(obj => obj.created_at >= + weekOneStartDate + 
obj.created_at <= weekFiveEndDate)
  console.log(DateArray.length);

}
```

1. I stored a date inside a variable
2. Now I am concatenating inside an array filter
3. `obj => obj.created_at >= + weekOneStartDate`
4. it is not working
5. How can we concatenate inside a function

Comment: You can use template literals: ```filter(obj => `${obj.created_at}>=${weekOneStartDate${obj.created_at}<=${weekFiveEndDate}`)```

Comment: Not filtering data, showing all the data

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. Could you update your question with what you expect to show?

Comment: You can't combine `>=` and `+` in a `filter` like that. Do the filter, then concatenated.

Comment: I am filtering array data based on created_date, instead of using dates, i am storing date range in a variable. and i am using inside function. Now how can i concatenate a variable with obj.created_at